# Get WordPress library image description from image title

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The problem is that i need to get the image description from the media library by using only the image title. It is not possible for me to use the attatchment ID. (Look at my code example for the why)

I've already tried to google the problem, but can't find the answer there or on stackoverflow. Only if i can use the attacthment ID

```
<?php $key_1_values = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'old_id' ); ?>

<div class="picture topbanner" style="background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/img-<?php echo $key_1_values[0] ?>.jpg');">
```

This is my currrent code for getting the ID. This issue occured because we need to import data from an old ASP system, and the only thing i could do was to put the image name in metadata and import all the images into the same month.

Hope this is enough information.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there's no WordPress function that does that for you, you'd have to write a custom query.

```php
global $wpdb;
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_content FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_title=%s", $key_1_values[0]);
$result = $wpdb->get_row($query);
```

This of course will cause problems if you have more than one image with the same name. Then you'd better get all the rows and do some more checks to determine which image you want.

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Function References:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_row/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/

Comment: Thanks a lot for an perfect solution :-)!

This works perfectly and is exactly what i need.. There will never be images with the same name in the library so this fits my needs for now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to @DRogueRonin

THE FINAL CODE IS:

```
<?php 
global $wpdb;
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_content FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_title=%s", $key_1_values[0]);
$result = $wpdb->get_row($query);
?>

<p>
<?php  $result = $wpdb->get_results($query); ?>
<?php echo $result[0]->post_content; ?>
</p>
```

Comment: You can remove the `$result = $wpdb->get_results($query);`. That's just when you need more than one row. `$wpdb->get_row($query)` gives you the first and only row already.

Comment: @DRogueRonin Oh, perfect! Thansk a lot :-)